FCM HTTP V1 support of Delay_While_Idle in AndroidGCMOptions
We are using Java Rest Client to hit the FCM HTTP V1
i am getting check the payload issue, while passing Delay_While_Idle in AndroidGCMOptions
my query is to check whether Delay_While_Idle in AndroidGCMOptions part of json payload and will it suppport in FCM HTTPV1?
